# How can I convert separate year columns into time series data in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

For example

```
      2017 2018 2019
Bill   10   15  20
Jim    5    10  20
```

I would like to then turn this into

```
Name Year Amount
Bill 2017 10 
Bill 2018 15 
Jim  2017 5
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for transpose :

```
df.T
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bill', 'Jim'],
                   2017 : [10, 5],
                   2018: [15,10],
                   2019: [20, 20]})
df = df.melt(id_vars=["name",],
        var_name="Year",
        value_name="Amount")
```